# lightdm failed to start session; user folder requesting Gnome

Tags: xorg, login, security, lightdm, authentication

We're migrating some old 10.10 users on Gnome to 14.04 using Unity. When they log on, however, the lightdm greeter complains "Failed to start session."  `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` notes:

```
[+181.14s] DEBUG: Session pid=3566: User thales authorized
[+181.15s] DEBUG: Session pid=3566: Greeter requests default session
[+181.15s] DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration gnome-classic
[+181.15s] DEBUG: Seat: Can't find session 'gnome-classic'
[+181.15s] DEBUG: Session pid=3566: Greeter start authentication
```

A successful login looks like:

```
[+113.16s] DEBUG: Session pid=1957: User ntimkovich authorized
[+113.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=1957: Greeter requests default session
[+113.17s] DEBUG: Seat: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+113.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=1957: Sending SIGTERM
...
```

Our migration is in an intermediate state, so I'd like to avoid obliterating profiles (e.g. `rm -rf ~/.gnome*`), and we're also trying to push people to just use one desktop (the stock Unity) for simplicity.

What is the specific folder/file that is causing the GUI to request 'gnome-classic' that I could perhaps temporarily hide?  Or even better, is there a way to tell lightdm (or whatever does this) that if it "can't find session 'X'" to revert to Unity?

Answer (score 2):

The user's `.Xauthority` file is the culprit. Moving the file and logging in will revert to the system defaults.